How to sync data between from a SQL DB in Azure SQL Server to another SQL DB in a same Azure SQL Server
I have a SQL server in Azure:
Az-SQL-SRV1
-> Az-DB-1
-> Az-DB-2

My app is always connecting to Az-DB-1 by design and Az-DB-2 is a backup DB. I want to always sync the Backup DB Az-DB-2 so that in cases when I have to switch from Primary to Backup I don't have to worry about the data loss.
Can't use Geo-Replication as both DB are in same zone and same SQL server.

Having a replica on the same environment generally isn't how you do things. This sounds like an XY Problem. What would you be doing in the "primary" database that would mean you need to fall to the secondary on the same server? If you make changes to the secondary and you expecting for those to then be pushed to the primary?

Is it SQL Server on Azure VM or SQL Server Managed Instance or Azure SQL?

why would you want to sync two dbs on the same server ?

SQL Data Sync is a service built on Azure SQL Database that lets you synchronize the data you select bi-directionally across multiple databases.
To setup SQL Data Sync Follow below procedure:

Go to your Azure SQL database that need to be replicated in azure portal, go to Data Management >> Sync to other databases >> New Sync Group.

Fill the required Data as below


